# Building OpenCV 2.4.10 + Windows 7 + Visual Studio 2013, guide and error solving

Tags: opencv, opengl, windows-7, cuda, tbb

I have been trying to build OpenCV 2.4.10 on Windows 7 32bit using Visual Studio 2013 and it has been a real pain. I have make some achivements but unfortunatelly it is not working 100%.

I would like to write a small manual not so focused on the step by step -it can be frustrating when one of those steps fails and you don't know how to reach the next one- and more focused on understanding what is happening on each step, why and what to expect when something goes wrong.
I ask for your help, sure you have faced lot of them before and can explain why it is happening.
I am downloading 3 to build with CMake 3.0.2 and Visual Studio 2013. I will update this thread as I take steps.

My aim is to build 2.4.10 with CUDA, TBB and OpenGL support. And make it work :)

- Clone OpenCV 2.4.10 (I am using TortoiseGit at C:\OpenCV\src\src)
- Download TBB Compiled
- Unzip TBB in C:\OpenCV\src\opt\tbb
- Unzip OpenCV source in C:\OpenCV\src dir
- Open CMake and target source dir C:\OpenCV\src and built dir C:\OpenCV\built
- Configure CMake for the first time

  - Select Visual Studio 12 2013, Use default native compilers for a configuration Win32
- Select this options:

  - Under WITH tab:

    - WITH_CUDA (already checked)
    - WITH_OPENGL
    - WITH_TBB
- And click configure again...

Here, OPENGL libs are found (opengl32 and glu32) and first missing paths appear (TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS), those for TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS, so:

- Point that line to C:\OpenCV\src\opt\tbb\include and click configure again.

After that configuration process, TBB tab appears in red with LIB_DIR and STDDEF_PATH labels pointed to my TBB folder.

- Click configure again to confirm the changes.

This time, there are no tag in red, and everything seems to be fine. I check the output and GUI OpenGL support is set to Yes, and so is Use TBB (ver 4.3 interface 8002) under Other third-party libraries, so

- Click Generate to generate the Visual Studio files

Files are generated, so

- Open Visual Studio 2013 and open OpenCV solution at C:\OpenCV\built and wait for it to be ready
- Select Debug and then Build Solution (Ctrl+Shift+B) and wait...
- First errors happen when it tries to find the core lib, so I re-run CMake for a simple build, without OpenGL, CUDA or TBB.
  I have found this [guide](http://initialneil.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/opencv-2-4-9-cuda-6-5-visual-studio-2013/):

Which point to several of the problems I have been having. After compiling with its recommendations now I am having a particular problem regarding throw_nogpu that I will look for.

Comment: This link is pretty useful:
http://initialneil.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/opencv-2-4-9-cuda-6-5-visual-studio-2013/

Answer (score 2):

This guide solved my problems with CUDA, OpenGL and TBB:

http://initialneil.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/opencv-2-4-9-cuda-6-5-visual-studio-2013/

I hope it helps.